$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \, dx$ converges iff $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2} \left( \int_{x-1}^{x+1} f(t) \, dt \right) dx$ converges
Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be an integrable function on every closed and bounded interval. Define:
$$g(x) = \frac{1}{2} \int_{x-1}^{x+1} f(t) \, dt$$
Prove or disprove: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \, dx$ converges if and only if $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x) \, dx$ converges.
To be honest I dont even know where to start tho my intuition thinks this should hold true but I have no clue on how to prove it and that makes me think it might diverge, but after trying some "counter examples" they all fail and I am not sure what to do.
and when I say I don't how to prove it, it seems like I can't play around with my information what I thought was defining F(x) as follows:
$$F(x) = \int_0^x f(t) \, dt$$
since f is riemann integrable we conclude that F is continuous and we can write g(x) as follows:$$g(x) = \frac{1}{2} \left[ F(x+1) - F(x-1) \right]$$
now what I tried is assuming the integral of f converges and thus we conclude that $$\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} g(x) = 0$$
then I tried using the integral comparison test but here comes the problem, I dont know whether or not f is bounded so I cant really do anything. and going from the direction of assuming g converges also fails miserably, I have no clue on how to start I really think it might be a disprove question. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Already answered ($\int g$ convergent does not imply $\int f$ convergent), but we can also show the other direction is true. In fact if $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x), dx$ converges, then $\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x), dx$ converges to the same value.

How would you show that? that is what I tried doing in the first place but didn't manage to since I dont know the behavior of f ( is f was bounded then I could work it out, but only the converges part (not the same value)) note that I cant use Fubini theorem btw

Or maybe not? I realized there might be a bit of a hole in my mental proof sketch.

But the basic idea is that $\int_a^{a+2N} f(x), dx$ approaches $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x), dx$ when $a$ is small and $a+2N$ is large and is also related to reversing the order of integration of $\int g(x), dx$. But there's those triangular bits at the ends of the 2D region. Usually those will have vanishing integrals, but maybe a counterexample would make something larger persist there.

in any case I can't reverse order of integration, we still haven't learned that xd

I think this is false. For example, take $f(x)=\sin(\pi x)$. For every $x\in\mathbb{R}$:
$$\int_{x-1}^{x+1}\sin(\pi t)dt=-\frac{\cos(\pi t)}{\pi}\Bigg|_{-1}^1=0$$
Therefore:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\int_{x-1}^{x+1}\sin(\pi t)dt\right)dx$$ converges. However, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin(\pi t)dt$ diverges.

Could you maybe explain how you manage to think about it? I really want to understand the thinking process

What do you mean? a constant function has a period of 2  but the integral of it (say f(x)=1) wont give me $0$

@SineoftheTime Not any function with period 2. That the integral over some one-period interval is zero is an additional requirement, which implies the integral is zero over any one-period interval.

for that to hold I need a bit more no? sin($\pi$x) is really working here since it has a period of 2 and it "cancel each other"

@aschepler right, I was not fully precise.

@amit2802: You build your thinking process by studying counterexamples such as the one Math101 provides here.
